# AzureDevOps OnPremise behind reverse-proxy

Tags: azure-devops-server-2019

is it possible to run Azure DevOps server behind reverse-proxy and give it an alias name?
Let's say I have server on HTTP://adps.domain:8080/tfs
And I want it to sit behind HTTPS://safe.adps.domain/tfs with reverse-proxy

Is it possible at all?

1. first issue I found was absolute addressing in web scripts and web resources, which made it unable to load due to CORS...
2. next I found, that VisualStudio takes the new azure DevOps server address and can see projects, but attempt to clone git project fails, as it requires port 8080 and HTTP, like this:
   The main server address in VS is HTTPS://safe.adps.domain, but cloning goes crazy,
   HTTP://safe.adps.domain:8080/tfs/...

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, partial answer:

It works for GIT projects if the git repository address is manually constructed and provided to VisualStudio, because the project tree does not work, can not construct the address to a project...

VisualStudio can read projects tree from https alias, but is unable to construct https address to target project, still constructing link as HTTP with port 8080...

With Web, it seems I was mistaken, not absolute addressing. It is using the new address but still enforcing HTTP and port 8080. Most likely renders reverse-proxy attempt useless :(...

Answer (score 0):

You should set the public URL as "https://safe.adps.domain". It works well, except the basic auth dialog always pops up when you work in a web browser. You access the collection, it pops up; you click the repositories, it pops up; you want to check some PR, and it pops up again. Which is absolutely annoying.

BTW, if you have done this before and never have or have already fixed this basic auth dialog issue, pls let me know how. It's killing me.